Update query not working with Celery and FastAPI
I am using a FastAPI repository pattern, and it works very well in Celery, but I have an Update query it doesn't execute. (The funny part is that, other queries work very well).
Here's my query:
UPDATE_REMINDER_SENT_AT_QUERY = """
UPDATE public.trainings
SET reminder_sent_at = :next_reminder_date  AT TIME ZONE 'utc'
WHERE id = :training_id
RETURNING id;
"""

Then here's my repository:
 async def update_reminder_sent_at(
        self, training_id: UUID, next_reminder_date
    ):
        async with self.db.transaction():
            record: int = await self.db.fetch_val(
                query=UPDATE_REMINDER_SENT_AT_QUERY,
                values={
                    "training_id": training_id,
                    "next_reminder_date": next_reminder_date,
                },
            )
            logger.info(f'record {record}')

And the service:
async def update_reminder_sent_at(
    self, training_id: UUID, next_reminder_date
):
    await self.repository.update_reminder_sent_at(training_id, next_reminder_date)

Then finally called in a Celery task:
@app_celery.task
def task_update(
    training_id: UUID, user_id: UUID, tenant_id: UUID
):
    """Send email reminders for a specific training and user."""

    async def send_reminder(training_id: UUID, user_id: UUID, tenant_id: UUID):
         next_reminder_date = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(
                    days=training.reminder.schedule_in_days
                )
                await training_service.update_reminder_sent_at(
                    training_id, next_reminder_date
                )

      asyncio.run(send_reminder(training_id, user_id, tenant_id))

So when I logged in the repository: logger.info(f'record {record}'), I get something like this:
celery_worker       | 2024-06-15 12:00:00.388 |INFO     | api.trainings.repository:update_reminder_sent_at:163 - record d1d33ada-1e98-40e7-982c-f553b09bcaa0 

Surprisingly checking the db, no effect made on the field. (The field didn't update at all).
laas_api=# select id, reminder_sent_at  from trainings
laas_api-# ;
                  id                  | reminder_sent_at
--------------------------------------+------------------
 b8b6b8d3-20ca-4ced-9720-4b6585f116d9 |
 3f9e08af-dacf-4979-97be-bbe3f86c5979 |
 fba1a12d-a8d9-418d-851a-a55e29c02996 |
 679596a0-264c-4dad-aca2-37c197534621 |
 24d3469d-bfa7-43f0-95b9-996105af6df0 |
 45213723-0711-4d86-97ef-d9c7528bcebd |
 d1d33ada-1e98-40e7-982c-f553b09bcaa0 |
(7 rows)

Note
Here's how my db is declared:
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_db():
    database = Database(
        settings.database_url, force_rollback=True, min_size=3, max_size=20
    )
    await database.connect()
    try:
        yield database
    finally:
        await database.disconnect()


Did you forget to commit the changes on the connection object?

Does this imply with raw sql ?

You always have to do await db_connection.commit() at some point in your code.

@lord_haffi,  I have added the db am using, I don't think it's the commit issue here, with raw SQL

Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. It doesn't matter if you're using raw SQL or some kind of mapper. You always have to commit changes if you want to persist the data in the database. It can be hidden behind a context manager sometimes. However, in the code snippet you posted, there isn't a commit present (on the connection object).

I just saw your update on the question. Can you try to add await database.commit() in the finally-block before disconnecting?

But am using a context manager. Check , I have added the get_db function. I don't think I need to commit

If you don't have the database connection configured to do an auto-commit upon closing, you have to do it explicitly, like I described.

I just noticed: You define a force rollback on your connection object. Of course, there will never be any data committed to your database. This is however what you generally want for your test cases. So it might be better to ask why you even want to commit the data to your database for your celery test?

So you mean, I change the roll-back field ?

If you want to commit data, yes.

From the documentation for force_rollback: "This will ensure that all database connections are run within a transaction that rollbacks once the database is disconnected."

Oooh, thanks so much, I think this makes a lot of sense @lord_haffi, let me try it out

Provide the answer and I vote it please. It worked well :)

We solved it in the comments, but for anyone encountering a similar issue, here is the answer:
You always have to commit your data in order to persist them on the database. In your get_db function you don't do any commit. Moreover, you configure your connection object with force_rollback=True which causes all your changes to rollback upon closing.
From the documentation:

This will ensure that all database connections are run within a transaction that rollbacks once the database is disconnected.

So removing this flag plus a commit before disconnecting should resolve your issue.
